# Internet Explorer button:active inner-padding

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Trident `<=9` seems to append something like an *inner-padding* to **active** [button](/questions/tagged/button) elements.

Is it possible to disable this *feature* by using css ?

[image: note: this is just a example, not a real world screenshot]

Comment: Yep. that's how buttons work in IE. It's from the WindowXP school of 3D effects for GUI widgets. If you don't want that effect, don't use a `button` element.

Comment: so it's a "feature" of trident ?

Comment: The "movement of the text" is normal, but in your screenshot, the text seems to have moved more than is normal. It usually only moves approximately 1px down and right. What's your HTML/CSS? A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) containing it would help. Also which version(s) of IE?

Comment: the image is just a example, not a screenshot. whatever, ie moves the inner-button text from 6 to 9. in my opinion it's a useless and bad feature. fu ms.

Comment: I thought it was some kind of bug that the text had moved *so much* :D

Comment: What an annoying "feature" of IE.

Comment: inner padding is just padding by the way, an outer padding would be a margin

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update:** For IE11+, [it can be removed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19593629/405015).

---

No, you can't get rid of it (in old versions of Internet Explorer).

As @Spudley said:

> If you don't want that effect, don't use a `button` element.

If it really matters, then an `a` element is the only alternative, but it's not really worth switching *just* to fix this. Users of Internet Explorer are used to it.

Comment: thank you thirtydot ! hope ms will erase this feature in common versions. regards.

Comment: Actually better always use button for actions that affect the website. And link for actions that do not affect at all. ([When to Use a Button or Link](http://uxmovement.com/buttons/when-to-use-a-button-or-link/))

Answer (score 25):

**In [Microsoft Internet Explorer 11+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531140%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can fix it!** Use **`position: relative`** for inner elements of button.

html:

```
<button><span>Submit</span></button>
```

css:

```
button > span{position:relative}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: **-1 This does not work for versions of trident behind 10.x !**

Comment: +1 Tested and this works on IE11 at least. That's great to have a solution for at least some versions of IE.

Comment: This also can help, a slight variation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203225/remove-3d-press-effect-internet-explorer-button

Comment: Doesn't work when my button has `display: inline-table`.

Comment: @mate64 how does Edge deal with updating?

Answer (score 1):

```
<button><span>Submit</span></button>
```

---

```
button:active > span {
 -ms-transform: translate(0px, -0.5px);
}
```

Comment: Works at least on IE 11 and, if doing `translate(-0.5px -0.5px)` it completely counters the "movement" of the button when it's being pressed. Also, by using the `-ms-transform` property it has no impact on any other browsers. To me, this is the best solution. No need not to use a button tag if it is a button